# How can I monitor the CPU usage of one process over a period of time?

Tags: windows-7, display, cpu-usage

I want to know what the average CPU usage is of a particular executable on my PC over a day.

I could write a C# app to do this, but I figured this is exactly the sort of app Superuser would know about if it exists!

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, in case it matters!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the Performance Monitor. Right-click on the graph and select "Add Counters".

In the "Available counters" list, open the "Process" section by clicking on the down arrow next to it. Select "% Processor Time" (and any other counter you want).

In the "Instances of selected object" list, select the process you want to track. Then click on "Add >>". Click on OK once you have what you need.

This will give a graph of the CPU usage for the chosen application.

Answer (score 4):

Another application that any Superuser should use is [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

See in Mark Russinovich's technical blog the article [The Case of the System Process CPU Spikes](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/04/07/3031251.aspx), where he tracked down a CPU spike caused by his network driver.

Comment: I use Process Explorer, but am not sure how to record CPU usage with it!

Comment: @joshcomley: read the above article. In short: Just double-click on the process and explore the available tabs.

Answer (score 1):

following command gets the average of cpu and memory usage every 50 second for specific process(pid)

```
pidstat 50 -ru -p <pid>
```

output for my case(firs two lines for cpu-usage, second two lines for memory):

```
02:17:47 PM       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
02:18:27 PM     24563    0.38    0.07    0.00    0.45     3  java

02:17:47 PM       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
02:18:27 PM     24563     11.68      0.00 13047972 2123268   6.52  java
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's link that may be of use to you: 
http://zamov.online.fr/EXHTML/CSharp/CSharp_927308.html

Otherwise, have a look through the System.Diagnostics namespace (a quick search on System.Diagnostics shows up the relevant page).